# What are the differences between these C# snippets (Outlook addin)?

Tags: c#, outlook

This is for an Outlook Addin, if that matters. I'm in the process of learning C# and I'm wondering if anyone could explain the differences between these two lines of code.

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox =
    Application.Session
    .GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

and

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox =
    this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    .GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

I suppose it boils down to usage of `this` and then `GetNamespace("MAPI")` vs `Session`. Does `Session` refer to the "MAPI" namespace here? When would it not? Is `this` ever necessary here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent:

> The Session property and the
>   GetNamespace method can be used
>   interchangeably to obtain the
>   NameSpace object for the current
>   session. Both members serve the same
>   purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.session.aspx

Comment: In this context, the use of `this` bears no meaning.

Comment: what's about using multiple smtp and Exchange accounts?